# What are the symbols for in Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2013, symbols

Every time I recompile my code Visual Studio debugger is looking for `symbols` it takes very long especially when I restart the app it has to load it all over again from the Microsoft server. Are the symbols necessary ? If not how to disable it or make the recompilation for debugging quicker ?

Comment: Just turn it off.  Tools + Options, Debugging, Symbols, untick the symbol server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are the symbols necessary ?

Symbols simply allow Visual Studio debugger to map addresses to function names.

PDB file contains Symbol & line information. PDB file is generated when your build your project.
*You can opt for no PDB file by changing Visual Studio settings.*

without PDB your program stack trace would look like this

```
0x00002130
```

with PDB

```
0x00002130 yourprogram!function
```

Microsoft has also built debug version of OS libraries such as KERNEL, GDI, etc., those are `Windows debug symbols`. Sometimes programmers need Windows debug symbols to investigate runtime errors. e.g. BSOD errors. Microsoft facilitates debug symbols download from their server.

@Hans suggested how you can turn off the settings.

Comment: *map hex addresses to function names* What if I have an address expressed in decimal or octal???