# Debugging source code via dll in another solutution (visual studio)

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, iis

This is working, I'd just like to know why :)

I have the source code open in one solution (MVC controllers) which on build does a robocopy of the compiled dll to the target solution.

The target is running in IIS and I can attach to the IIS process from visual studio in the *source* solution and my breakpoints get hit while performing actions in the destination project - are both projects sharing a reference in memory or something?

```
1>     Source : C:\source\uCommerce.RazorStore\bin\
1>       Dest : F:\destination\bin\
1>  
1>      Files : uCommerce.RazorStore.dll
  Options : /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30
```

Comment: Because the symbol files generated contain the necessary information for the debugger to locate the corresponding source files. If you move the source files to another location, then the debugger would report an error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the symbols for in Visual Studio debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27607547/what-are-the-symbols-for-in-visual-studio-debugger)